# Code that runs in instances and stops for 5 minutes before running again

Tags: java, sql, algorithm, while-loop

I want to run my code in instances for each instance the code pulls data from my database as a result set and stop  waits for another 5 mins pulls the result set and stop. The program should never end. The problem is the program waits for 5 minutes at the first instance but does wait again it runs continues
Below is the code. The result set and database connection part are okay

```
package postilion_error.checker;

/**
 *
 * @author kithinjid
 */
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.logging.*;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import static sun.font.FontManager.logger;

public class POSTILION_ERRORCHECKER {


  static Logger log;
  static Handler file_handler;
  Connection conn=null;
  Statement st=null;
  static ResultSet rs=null;
  static int i = 0;
  static int counter=0;
  static boolean checker=true;


    private  void dbconnect()
    {
        String username="Postilion";
        String password="Password12";

        String hostname="jdbc:sqlserver://172.16.112.6;databaseName=realtime";
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection(hostname,username,password);
            System.out.println("TIME:"+dateString("MM:dd-HH:mm:ss")+":connected to database");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    private ResultSet check_00(String query1)
    {
        dbconnect();     

        try
        {
        st=conn.createStatement();
        rs=st.executeQuery(query1);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return rs ;
    }
    public static void scheduled()
    {


         Timer timer=new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
   public void run() {
    while(checker==true)
    {
    log=logger.getLogger("my logger");
    try {
    file_handler=new FileHandler("C:\\Users\\kithinjid\\Google Drive\\interswitch\\NetBeansProjects\\POSTILION_ERROR CHECKER\\dist\\logg.txt");
    SimpleFormatter formatter=new SimpleFormatter();
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter);
    log.addHandler(file_handler);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    log.info(dateString("HHmmss"));
    Logger.getLogger(POSTILION_ERRORCHECKER.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SecurityException ex)
    {
    Logger.getLogger(POSTILION_ERRORCHECKER.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    String query="SELECT TOP 100 [tran_nr]\n" +
"      ,[gmt_date_time]\n" +
"      ,[time_local]\n" +
"      ,[date_local]\n" +
"      ,[sink_node]\n" +
"      ,[rsp_code_req_rsp]\n" +
"      ,[rsp_code_cmp]\n" +
"      ,[rsp_code_rev]\n" +
"  FROM [realtime].[dbo].[tm_trans_10] where sink_node = 'GTBUSDsnk' ORDER BY tran_nr desc";
       POSTILION_ERRORCHECKER pe=new POSTILION_ERRORCHECKER();
       pe.dbconnect();


    try
    {
      ResultSet result=pe.check_00(query);

       while(result.next()==true)
       {
          //loop for counter and displaying
      int response=Integer.parseInt(result.getString("rsp_code_req_rsp"));
     System.out.println(response);
     if (response==91)
     {
     counter++;
    if (counter>=10)
    System.out.println("TIME:"+dateString("MM:dd-HH:mm:ss")+"--error respose code:91 of count:"+ counter+" to sink node GTBUSDsnk");
     }

       }
       }catch(Exception e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
                       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                    }
                    }
                },30000,30000); 

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        scheduled();
        System.out.println("execution started");
    }
    private static String dateString(String formart)
    {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(formart);
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }


}
```

Comment: Can't really read the unformatted code, but what's the ultimate question or what issue are you facing?

Comment: @DaveNewton i need the code to run once pick the result set and stop for 5min then pick again

Comment: Simply use Quartz scheduling library, no need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: i think there should be a java code solution for that

Comment: What is the ,30000,30000 this is not valid syntax. Yes no library needed, Thread.sleep will do the job.

Comment: @maraca that is java syntax for timer . Please read more on java Timers

Comment: @DENNISKITHINJI it comes from the anonymous TimerTask but with that formatting you cannot see anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function named delay() as follows, and then call the function whenever you want to wait for 5 mins. But this might block your program, and also it won't work if you need something else done in the meanwhile...

```
private void delay()
{
    try {
         Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);
    } catch(Exception e) { }
}
```

Comment: You can still do other stuff while waiting, but you will have to use another thread.

Comment: @maraca the waiting time is for doing some logic. The code gets response codes from postilion database this is ISO8583 switching for banks and financial institutions. Hence the waiting time is for analyzing the result-set from the database and also for waiting more transactions to take place

Comment: @user1637645 can i use that code when am not using thread in my code i have not inherited the thread functionality

Comment: @DENNISKITHINJI yes u can... Thread class is in the java.lang package which is imported by default, and Thread.sleep() is a static function... Besides, Thread.sleep() puts the "currently executing" thread to sleep, and since there is always a main thread (even if you haven't explicitly created one), you can use this function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @user1637645  here is the working code

```
package postilion_error.checker;

/**
 *
 * @author kithinjid
 */
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.logging.*;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import static sun.font.FontManager.logger;

public class POSTILION_ERRORCHECKER {


  static Logger log;
  static Handler file_handler;
  Connection conn=null;
  Statement st=null;
  static ResultSet rs=null;
  static int i = 0;
  static int counter=0;
  static boolean checker=true;


    private  void dbconnect()
    {
        String username="Postilion";
        String password="Password12";

        String hostname="jdbc:sqlserver://172.16.112.6;databaseName=realtime";
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection(hostname,username,password);
            System.out.println("TIME:"+dateString("MM:dd-HH:mm:ss")+":connected to database");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    private ResultSet check_00(String query1)
    {
        dbconnect();     

        try
        {
        st=conn.createStatement();
        rs=st.executeQuery(query1);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return rs ;
    }
    public static void scheduled()
    {


         Timer timer=new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
   public void run() {
    while(checker==true)
    {
    log=logger.getLogger("my logger");
    try {
    file_handler=new FileHandler("C:\\Users\\kithinjid\\Google Drive\\interswitch\\NetBeansProjects\\POSTILION_ERROR CHECKER\\dist\\logg.txt");
    SimpleFormatter formatter=new SimpleFormatter();
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter);
    log.addHandler(file_handler);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    log.info(dateString("HHmmss"));
    Logger.getLogger(POSTILION_ERRORCHECKER.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SecurityException ex)
    {
    Logger.getLogger(POSTILION_ERRORCHECKER.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    String query="SELECT TOP 100 [tran_nr]\n" +
"      ,[gmt_date_time]\n" +
"      ,[time_local]\n" +
"      ,[date_local]\n" +
"      ,[sink_node]\n" +
"      ,[rsp_code_req_rsp]\n" +
"      ,[rsp_code_cmp]\n" +
"      ,[rsp_code_rev]\n" +
"  FROM [realtime].[dbo].[tm_trans_10] where sink_node = 'GTBUSDsnk' ORDER BY tran_nr desc";
       POSTILION_ERRORCHECKER pe=new POSTILION_ERRORCHECKER();
       pe.dbconnect();


    try
    {
      ResultSet result=pe.check_00(query);

       while(result.next()==true)
       {
          //loop for counter and displaying
      int response=Integer.parseInt(result.getString("rsp_code_req_rsp"));
     System.out.println(response);
     if (response==91)
     {
     counter++;
    if (counter>=10)
    System.out.println("TIME:"+dateString("MM:dd-HH:mm:ss")+"--error respose code:91 of count:"+ counter+" to sink node GTBUSDsnk");
     }
    }
         delay();
       }catch(Exception e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
                       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                    }
                    }
                },0,30000); 

    }
    public static void delay()
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        scheduled();
        System.out.println("execution started");

    }
    private static String dateString(String formart)
    {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(formart);
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: The output is posed for 5 minutes before the next connection to database